# Having trouble applying D.R.Y. to my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I need help simplifying my code. I'm trying to apply the D.R.Y. principle as best as I can and I'm having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    var body = $('body');

    body.find('#button1').click(function(){
         body.find('#item1').add('#item2').fadeOut();
         body.find('#item3').fadeIn();
         body.find('#button1').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
         body.find('#button2').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });

    body.find('#button2').click(function(){
        body.find('#item3').fadeOut();
        body.find('#item1').add('#item2').fadeIn();
        body.find('#button2').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
        body.find('#button1').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using just `$` for accessing elements that are unique, you might also like this as an improvement for reuse and readability,

```
function makeInfo(id) {
  $(id).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
}
function makeDefault(id) {
  $(id).removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    $('#button1').click(function(){
         $('#item1').add('#item2').fadeOut();
         $('#item3').fadeIn();
         makeInfo('#button2');
         makeDefault(this);             
    });

    $('#button2').click(function(){
        $('#item3').fadeOut();
        $('#item1').add('#item2').fadeIn();
        makeInfo('#button1');
        makeDefault(this);             
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that one item of DRY that can be applied is for the class part:

```
//add event bound to the click of a element with class btn-default
body.on('click', '.btn-default', function () {
    //remove btn-default from this class and add btn-info
    $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    //remove btn-info from this class and add btn-default
    $('.btn-info').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
});
```

making the whole code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    var body = $('body');

    //add event bound to the click of a element with class btn-default
    body.on('click', '.btn-default', function () {
        //remove btn-default from this class and add btn-info
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
        //remove btn-info from this class and add btn-default
        $('.btn-info').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
    });

    body.find('#button1').click(function(){
         body.find('#item1').add('#item2').fadeOut();
         body.find('#item3').fadeIn();
    });

    body.find('#button2').click(function(){
        body.find('#item3').fadeOut();
        body.find('#item1').add('#item2').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no unnecessary repetition, but there is unnecessary code. For example, no need to begin at `$('body')` and `.find()` the next tags.

Instead, follow this pattern:

(1) remove `var body = $('body');` -- no need for it

(2) Make these changes:

```
body.find('#button1').click( -- can be -- $('#button1').click(

body.find('#item1').add('#item2').fadeOut(); == $('#item1').add('#item2').fadeOut();

body.find('#item3').fadeIn();  ==  $('#item3').fadeIn();
```

etc.

---

Update: To reduce DOM searches, cache the entire selector:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    'use strict';
    var $i1 = $('#item1');
    var $i3 = $('#item3')
    var $b1 = $('#button1');
    var $b2 = $('#button2');

    $b1.click(function(){
         $i1.add('#item2').fadeOut();
         $i3.fadeIn();
         $b1.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
         $b2.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });

    $b2.click(function(){
        $i3.fadeOut();
        $i1.add('#item2').fadeIn();
        $b2.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
        $b1.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the reason I had the $body and .find was to bring the number of times i searched the DOM to only once. Not really for the performance of this code specifically but to make it a practice for future, much larger, project

Comment: Just that won't reduce searching the DOM -- the `.find()` searches the DOM. To reduce searching the DOM, see edits to my answer

Comment: Thank you, through some resources I found, it stated that that calling the selector once would sort of cache everything that is within it, and ```.find()``` would search through that selection.

Comment: `body.find('#button1').click()` === `$('#button1').click()` *(They are the same)*

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function (say 'toggleElements') that takes a flag and performs all the actions required depending on the value of the flag and then do this:

```
body.find('#button1').click(function() {
    toggleElements(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any problems in your code, and any changes will not improve readability. It is not always *"do whatever you can, but do not repeat a single line of code"* - you need find the optimum, and your looks actually good.

However, there are some possible improvements:

1. Why do you use body if your element IDs are unique? You can simply use selector.
2. You can combine selector instead of using `.add`.

Something like:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    $('#button1').click(function(){
         $('#item1, #item2').fadeOut();
         $('#item3').fadeIn();
         $('#button1').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
         $('#button2').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });

    $('#button2').click(function(){
        $('#item3').fadeOut();
        $('#item1,#item2').fadeIn();
        $('#button2').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default');
        $('#button1').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-info');
    });
});
```

Another options are to combine this functionality into one function with boolean argument or use CSS classes and transitions. As I said, in my opinion, 4 lines of code are OK to not be "optimized". If your functions grow up - optimize it.

Comment: Thank you, I was using the body selector and find to bring the times I searched the DOM to once in the script. It's not really for the performance of this script but making it a practice to search the DOM as few times as possible. Mostly this is me trying to make practice of clean code, I'm expecting much larger projects in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, where you define which items are to be shown by using a `data` attribute on each button. This has the benefit of needing less work when you need to add more buttons or items, and works for any buttons/items combination.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tut79rb4/)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="btn-info" value="Button 1" data-show="#item1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" class="btn-default" value="Button 2" data-show="#item2" />
<input type="button" id="button3" class="btn-default" value="Button 3" data-show="#item2, #item3" />

<div id="item1" class="itemClass">Item 1</div>
<div id="item2" class="itemClass">Item 2</div>
<div id="item3" class="itemClass">Item 3</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-default', function() {
  var show = $(this).data('show');
  $('.itemClass').not(show).fadeOut();
  $(show).fadeIn();

  $('.btn-info').addClass('btn-default').removeClass('btn-info');
  $(this).addClass('btn-info').removeClass('btn-default');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll definitely be using this in the future